# How to remove window background image of splash screen when application navigates to another activity (to avoid memory leak)

Tags: android, memory-leaks, xamarin, splash-screen

In my Xamarin android application i am showing splash screen for 3 seconds ,when application starts. In that duration i do background work for creating sqlite tables, loading user information from web if required for login. These tasks are done using async manner.

I have assigned theme for splashactivity , and in that theme I have assigned background as one jpeg file that is of 37 KB, with dimentions of 400*692.

After 3 seconds i navigate to my startActivity, and in onDestroy of SplashScreen activity, I am assigning another theme to window with background set to null. But still if I take a snapshot of heap and examine in MAT, it shows that SplashActivity with Leak Suspect having 4.4 MB (13% of total heap). I am attaching code for SplashActivity as well as for styles.

Please let me know how do i avoid this leak?

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.SplashActivity", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class SplashScreen : BaseActivity
{
    private AndroidDALProvider dalProvider;
    public AndroidDALProvider DalProvider
    {
        get { return (dalProvider ?? (dalProvider = new AndroidDALProvider())); }
    }
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {

        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        //Display Splash Screen for 3 Sec  
        AndroidDALProvider.InitializeTables();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        TablesCreated();

        //Start Activity1 Activity  
        StartActivity(typeof(LoginActivity));            
    }

    private void TablesCreated()
    {
        LoadData("283");
        LoadData("284");
        LoadData("248");
        LoadData("249");
    }

    private void LoadData(string userID)
    {
        DalProvider.GetPatInfoWithID(userID,PatInfoLoadedFromSqlite);
    }

    private void PatInfoLoadedFromSqlite(PatientDemographicsDTOUI patientInfo, string patID)
    {
        if (patientInfo == null)
            LoadDataFromInternet(patID);
    }

    private void LoadDataFromInternet(string userID)
    {
        //Check for internet connection
        if (IsNetworkAvailable)
        {
            //set loggedinuser details for this user
            try
            {
                ServiceProvider.GetPatDemographics(userID).ContinueWith(PatDemographicsReceived);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                ShowMessage(ApplicationContext, exception.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ShowMessage(ApplicationContext, "Network not available");
            //ShowPatInfoScreen();
        }
    }

    void PatDemographicsReceived(Task<PatientDemographicsDTO> patient)
    {
        if (patient != null)
        {
            //Fill the received data into local storage
            DalProvider.AddPatInfoToStorage(patient.Result.GetUIModel(), PatInfoAddedToLocal);
        }            
    }

    private void PatInfoAddedToLocal(int obj)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        dalProvider = null;
        SetTheme(Resource.Style.Theme_SplashActivityNoBG);
        base.OnDestroy();
    }
}
```

Here is a style for splash screen.

```
<style name="Theme.SplashActivity" parent="CustomHoloTheme">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

This style I am applying in OnDestroy of splash activity

```
<style name="Theme.SplashActivityNoBG" parent="CustomHoloTheme">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```